# Bibliography style: PDF should follow exactly the same bib file

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

In bib file, I used like this:

```
@article{novoselov2004electric,
   title={{}},
   author={K.S. Novoselov, A.K. Geim, S.V. Morozov, D. Jiang, Y. Zhang, S.V. Dubonos,  I.V. Grigorieva, A.A. Firsov},
  journal="Science",
  year="2004",
  volume="306",
  pages="666--669", 
  publisher={American Association for the Advancement of Science}
}
```

In pdf it is coming as follows:

```
V. Morozov D. Jiang Y. Zhang S.V. Dubonos I.V. Grigorieva A.A. Firsov K.S. Novoselov, A.K. Geim.
. Science, 306:666–669, 2004.
```

Please see that, authors ordering has been changed. Also year should come after Science. Name of publisher should also come. I am using \bibliographystyle{unsrt}

How to tackle this?

Comment: If you don't like the output of your bibliography style, either choose another style which matches your requirements or have a look at biblatex. Biblatex makes it easier to customise the output.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz or fix the syntax errors in the input:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That, too :)

Answer (score 2):

Authors should be separated by `and` not `,`   .

Commas are used to separate `surname, first names` so your bib file entry has just one author with a very long name.

```
author={K.S. Novoselov and A.K. Geim and S.V. Morozov
       and  D. Jiang and Y. Zhang and S.V. Dubonos
       and  I.V. Grigorieva and A.A. Firsov}
```